# Azure logic app : Error fetching the deployment template. SQL connector

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

When I try to start with a logic app, I always get following error : "Error fetching the deployment template."

We'd like to fix this issue, but it's very difficult with no error message and no response. Has anyone else experienced this and how did you fix it?